# A Minimization Problem Involving a Summation

Tags: optimization

Please help me with the following problem:
$$\text{minimize  }\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}{{{m}_{i}}.\left( \frac{{{m}_{i}}-1}{2} \right)},$$
subjected to:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}{{{m}_{i}}=n-1},$$  and 
$$t<\frac{n}{2},$$
where ${{m}_{i}}$  and $t$ are natural numbers.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Use the quadratic-mean inequality:

\begin{eqnarray*}E:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^t{m_i\left( \frac{m_i-1}{2} \right)} &=&   {1\over 2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^t(m^2_i-m_i)\\
&\geq &{1\over 2t}\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^tm_i\Big)^2-{1\over 2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^tm_i \\ &=& {1\over 2t}(n-1)^2-{1\over 2}(n-1)\\
&>& {1\over n}(n-1)^2-{1\over 2}(n-1)\\
&=& {(n-1)(n-2)\over 2n}
\end{eqnarray*}

Well, we can be a little more accurate:

If $n$ is even, then $t$ is at most ${n\over 2}-1$ so $E_{\min} ={n(n-1)\over 2(n-2)}$ and this is achieved when $m_1=m_2=...=m_t = {n-1\over t} = {2n-2\over n-2}$.

Similarly analysis goes if $n$ is odd. Then $t$ is at most $n-1 \over 2$ so $E_{\min} ={n-1\over 2}$ and this is achieved when $m_1=m_2=...=m_t = 2$.

Comment: tnx very much for this accurate answer